# Skip browser cache when site loads

Tags: html, web, caching, browser-cache

The problem is that my browser shows me an older version of my website so I had to clear my browser cache.

What can I implement something in my website to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some numeric characters with a `?` at the end of your file name. The browser will ignore it but it will not loading from the cache.

Something like: `index.html` to `index.html?version=23421412423`.

You can use a random number generator to do so.

Comment: I can't add special characters in the file name unfortunately.

Comment: Not in file name. In address to the file. Like: src="index.html?488632"

Comment: Ah, I understand now, but can it be any number or does it matter how long is it etc.?

Comment: Any number will do. Just change it whenever you wanted to skip the cache

Comment: It still loads from the cache for some reason.
<li><a href="projects/projects.html?22421412423">Projektek</li> 
<li><a class="active" href="index.html?23421412423">Kezdőlap</a></li>

Comment: Probably you used that new number before too

Comment: I changed the number mutiple times, still loads from cache. :/

Comment: That's odd... cause I did the same thing so many times in different cases and it worked. I will search for an alternative tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: I checked my latest publishes and that way is exactly what I've implemented and it works fine. Nothing else yet.

Comment: For me, I started with 1 and I increment it with each deploy.

Comment: I'll try it, thanks!

Comment: Do you need this cache skip on all files?

Comment: Yes, I need them on all files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239839/discussion-between-skyblue-and-jayden).

Comment: put a key value instead of just a number. that will do the thing. I edited the answer @Jayden

Comment: It seems to work.. for now at least. Thank you for the help, again.